# Freidlin Wentzell for stochastic differential inclusions

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations, large-deviations

Consider the SDI

$$dX^\varepsilon(t)\in b(X^\varepsilon(t))\,dt + \varepsilon \sigma(X^\varepsilon(t)) \, dB(t).$$

Is there any Freidlin-Wentzell large deviations principle for $X^\varepsilon$?